# Is there anyway to bring web @Context into JUnit (CXF+Spring)

Tags: spring, junit, jax-rs, cxf

I am trying to create unit test environment to test RESTFul services (cfx+spring) in my dev environemnt. To test RESTFul Services, I require @Context within JUnit test cases. @Context should contain HttpRequest, HttpSession, ServletContext, ServletConfig and all other webserver related information.

I have setup the JUnit for the above, but when I run, @Context is coming as null. This could be because there is no webserver running and there is no @Context. I am just doubting whether there is a way to created sample web @Context and pass to JUnit. Any other ideas are welcome to bring web @Context into JUnit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed a web container.

Try for example Jetty as an embedded container.

This [article](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42315/1954) contains useful information.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the option.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has some help for mocking the web server environment and thus testing without a real web container.  See these Spring Framework [docs on testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html) to get started.  I haven't used this in your context, but it may be helpful.